# Consul is throwing error of spring boot health Url (401)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

I have configured consul with my spring boot application, I have **basic Auth** to access the url.

If I hit localhost:8081/health it is asking for basic authentication and **status is UP**

but in consul UI  it is throwing an error

```
HTTP GET http://192.168.1.155:8081/health: 401  Output: HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

How can I provide this authentication in consul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled the security health in spring boot application and it's working fine because to check  health we don't need any security